# Where to put FirstOrDefault() in this linq to sql?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I need to put FirstOrDefault() in this linq query, any ideas what I need to reshuffle or do to make it fit, I guess it shouldn't be a .tolist anymore because theres gonna be only one record. Never used FirstOrDefault before, I've seen it appear in the select clause as well as in the where clause on forums. I am confused.

```
Public Class GetUserInfoFromUserID
    Public userCode As Integer
    Public nameCode As String
    Public fullName As String
    Public barCode As String
    Public email As String
    Public info As String
    Public departmentCode As Integer
    Public departmentName As String
    Public dateCreated As DateTime
    Public active As Boolean
End Class

Public Function [getUserFromID](userCode As Integer) As List(Of GetUserInfoFromUserID)
    Using db = New STleanappsDataContext()
        Return (From scan_Users In db.scan_Users
                        Join department In db.scan_Departments
                        On department.departmentCode Equals scan_Users.departmentCode
                        Where scan_Users.userCode = userCode
                        Select New GetUserInfoFromUserID() With {
                            .userCode = scan_Users.userCode,
                            .nameCode = scan_Users.nameCode,
                            .fullName = scan_Users.fullName,
                            .barCode = scan_Users.barCode,
                            .email = scan_Users.email,
                            .departmentCode = scan_Users.departmentCode,
                            .departmentName = department.departmentName,
                            .dateCreated = scan_Users.dateCreated,
                            .active = scan_Users.active
                         }).ToList()
    End Using
 End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `.ToList()` with `.FirstOrDefault()` and change the return type of the function to `GetUserInfoFromId`.

`ToList()` will get all the entries that match the query while `FirstOrDefault()` will get the first entry that matches the query or a default value (`Nothing` in your case)

[This resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.100).aspx) might be useful to you in the future, specifically the **Paging Methods** section. It tells you what methods are supported and you can click on their links for more information. Methods like `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, etc are there.

Comment: Damn youuuuu! I was so close! :P I forgot to redefine the return type at the top of the function. Thanks for the fast answer man. :) Also I would have given you an up vote, but apparently I need to get 15 achievement points